# What is this code doing? C/C++

Tags: c++, c

Can someone tell what this recursive function actually is doing. I think it does nothing, it returns 0 and program stops.

For string: `honolulu\0`

```
int fun(char *string){
    if(*string != 'u') return 0;
    return 1 + fun(string + 1);
}
```

Comment: It's _evil_ ! Hint : if your string does'nt contain any `u`, you'll get a segfault. Otherwise, it will simply count the number of characters preceding the first `u` of the given string

Comment: how about running it and see? if you wanted, you could even ptrint out the result of 1 + fun(string + 1);

Comment: It'll be better question if you explain more about what you've tried and why you think like that.

Comment: It reckon the successive `'u'` from the beginning.

Comment: Run in a debugger, and step through the code line by line, entering the recursive call (if it comes that far).

Comment: Also, there's no such languages as "C/C++". C and C++ are two *very* different languages, even if parts of their syntax is similar.

Comment: @Rerito if the string doesn't contain any 'u' it returns 0. the function simply counts number of 'u' in a row from the beginning of the string. why do you think it makes a segfault? i can't understand

Comment: @AndreyChernukha, suppose the string is dynamically allocated and is 6 byte-long. Its content is `"hello\0"`. After having checked the last character `*(string+5)` (`\0`), which is `!= 'u'`, we will call the function again and dereference `string+6` which is not allocated ...

Comment: @Rerito, if the string content is `"hello\0"` then the first line of the function will return 0 and stop recursing when it encounters `'h'` as the first character (`h` != `u`).

Comment: Oh yes my bad ! Didnt read carefully enough. Still if the string is full of `u` and not null terminated, the risk remains (although much more unlikely)

Answer (score 2):

It counts the number of 'u's at the start of the string.

```
cout << fun("umbrella"); //prints: "1"
cout << fun("uumbrella"); //prints: "2"
```

Note that it assumes the string is '\0' terminated. Similarly to many old C string functions it will iterate off the end of the array until it finds a random '\0' somewhere in memory as long as it keeps getting 'u's.

Comment: @Henrik A fair point. I guess I was just trying to explain that "uuu" was a legitimate string to pass.

Comment: @JoachimNilsson Don't forget to downvote [dido](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4112323/dido) and [Vlad from Moscow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2877241/vlad-from-moscow) I just hate feeling like I'm the only one.

Comment: @JoachimNilsson I'm a fan of not getting downvoted. How should I edit my answer?

Comment: @JoachimNilsson I have to say at some level I agree with you. I don't want to do *all* of someone's homework, but if it's a focused question, isn't that what StackOverflow is about answering? I mean I've asked some pretty dumb questions that may have seemed simple enough to be homework to some people.

Answer (score 1):

The function returns the index of the first character in a string that is not equal to character `'u'` You may consider it as a function that searches the first character not eual to `'u'` or a function that counts how many characters `'u'` are in the beginning of a string.

I would write it like

```
size_t fun( const char *s )
{
    return  *s != 'u' ? 0 : 1 + fun( s + 1 );
}
```

So for string literal `"honolulu"` the function will return 0 because the string literal does not contain initial 'u'.

If you need to find the first character `'u'` in a string then the function should be written like

```
size_t fun( const char *s )
{
    return  *s == 'u' || *s == '\0' ? 0 : 1 + fun( s + 1 );
}
```

In this case for the string literal shown above the function will return 5. It is the position of the first character `'u'` in the string literal

If you want to find any character in a string then the function can be defined like

```
size_t find( const char *s, char c )
{
    return  *s == c || *s == '\0' ? 0 : 1 + fun( s + 1, c );
}
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in the second example.  Shouldn't one of the tests be for `*s == '\0'?

Comment: @James Kanze  Yes it was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

**What the Code does:**

Your code counts the number of consecutive `u` letters in the string and it terminates when it finds first letter that is not `u` whether it is an alphabet or a `\0`. It will never traverse the whole string if any of the letter is not `u` because the sequence will be broken.
Basically it is a [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_function) and the base condition makes it to terminate if the letter is not `u`, otherwise it will make another recursive call.

**Behavior of Code in Your Case:**
For the given input `honolulu\0`, applying the scenario that pointer to the first index of array (which points to 'h') is passed to the function, then it will return `0` because at the very first comparison, it will find a letter that is not `u` so it will return from there, hence no recursive calls will be made that can return a non-zero integer so the output will be definitely `0`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are checking for first character in the string which is not character 'u' so it is terminating by returning 0.